# How to capture the displayed link in HTML (JavaScript) and pass to another HTML page as a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am building a website (and I am a novice) and the site has 2 frames.  On the left side (frame 1), I have a list of links that when you click on a link it will load a page in frame 2 (right side).  But the links are on the left side are actually the result of a query and will change.

Rather than hard coding a site for each link, I want to use one target page to display data.  I want to use the link on the left side as a variable value to pass to the right side so I can use the link name in a query on the target page.

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(top.frames[2].location.href='Recap.html');">MyUniqueLink</a>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: When you say "frame", are you talking about `<iframe>` elements?

Comment: I think OP means actual `<frame>` elements, which are outdated but still valid HTML tags.

Comment: A little more info on how the queries work might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data in your `<a>`'s, you should start by giving them an `id`:

```
<a id = "myId" href="JavaScript:void(top.frames[2].location.href='Recap.html');" >MyUniqueLink</a>
```

Then you can grab their data using standard js:

```
document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML; // grabs MyUniqueLink
document.getElementById("myId").getAttribute("href"); // resolves to href value
```

Or accomplish the same using jQuery:

```
$("#myId").html();
$("#myId").attr("href");
```

If you are dynamically creating the `<a>'s` in the first place, you can also assign them an id at this point using `newElement.setAttribute("id", "someNewId");`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `<iframe>`, you can access the parent document like so:

```
// window.parent will be undefined if you are not in an iframe.
window.parent.document
```

Then, as spencer said, it would be easier for you to use `document.getElementById("secondFrameId")` to get to your second iframe.
Also, the `onclick` event might be a bit more suited to your needs.

So together the code would look like:

```html
<a onclick="window.parent.document.getElementById('secondFrameId').src='http://example.com'">MyUniqueLink</a>
```